# Stream tweets in tweepy only by user id

Tags: python, twitter, stream, attributes, tweepy

While this code does display tweets by the user, But even if the user is mentioned by someone, then the tweets display.
In short, how to just display tweets by user and not Mentions and not retweets.

```
class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, data):
        try:
            if (not data.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in data.text):

                print(data.text)
                print(data.user.name)
                    #print(data.user.location)
                    #print tweetf
                saveThis=str(time.ctime())+'::'+data.text+'/n'
                saveFile = open('twitDB3.txt','a')
                saveFile.write(saveThis)
                saveFile.write('\n')
                saveFile.close()
                return(True)
        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed on data,',str(e)
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(follow=["87725838498"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code will give you user tweets. Update kwargs data according to you

```
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
kwargs = {'screen_name': <Username of user>,'include_rts': 0, 'count': <Number of tweets, max:200>}
tweets = api.user_timeline(**kwargs) #tweet object has tweets of user
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, as OP was asking about streaming.